Identify this slasher TV movie about a masked killer
I search a not very well-known slasher movie that I've seen around 2002. 
I have absolutely no idea about the title.
It must be an american movie. Spoken in english. It was realized in the beginning of 2000 I think. It was a color movie. it's about the investigation of a killer's murders. 
I only remember some sequences. In the beginning, the killer wants to kill three friends woman who are together in a house our in an appartment maybe. They arrive to escape him and go in a motel, but the killer retrieve them. 
In a moment, one of the three woman runs and the killer launches a knife that plants in the woman's back. Finally, the three woman are killed. 
At the end, there are one brown and thin woman, maybe a reporter, one man and a cop and they unmask the killer. The woman discovers that he's her nephew and he stays quiet. I believe he's a mentally handicapped person. 

Please see Identify-This-X Questions guide on how to write good identify this movie question. For example add better descriptive title, origin-country, colour, decade, language, plot details, actors etc. of the movie. I highly recommend doing that - otherwise it will be closed in day or two.

You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.
